# Create a time from separate components and divide it by given input

Tags: c#, time

Warehouse picking times verification.

I believe the pick rate at work that is being displayed has recently been manipulated to add seconds to each pickers rate, because they had reached the rate set out, but suddenly there all at least 2 seconds slower then previously shown.
So i want to be able to verify the time.
I have a WFA with the following

Input:

- (TextBox1) Lines Picked eg. 120.
- (TextBox2) Hours Picking eg. 02.
- (TextBox3) Minutes Picking eg. 03.
- (TextBox4) Seconds Picking eg. 44.
- (TextBox5) Milliseconds Picking eg. 7100000

Output:

- (TextBox6) Average pick rate = eg. 17.30 seconds

Can someone please show me an example of the method needed to convert the values entered to format 02:03:44.7100000 and calculate the average and output the value eg. 17.30 seconds.

```
 private void linesTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     lines = Convert.ToInt32(pickRateBox.Text);
  }

  private void hoursTbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     hours = Convert.ToInt32(hoursTbox.Text);

  }

  private void minTbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     mins = Convert.ToInt32(minTbox.Text);

  }

  private void secTBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     secs = Convert.ToInt32(secTBox.Text);
  }

  private void mSTbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     millisec = Convert.ToInt32(mSTbox.Text);


  }

  private void ratePick(int h, int m, int s, int mil)
  {
     DateTime dt = new DateTime(00, 00, 00, h, m, s, mil);





  }
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Parsing integers, creating a DateTime instance from those integers and then dividing that DateTime is quite trivial.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a `TimeSpan` rather than a `DateTime`... this is an elapsed time, not a time within a day, by the looks of it...

Comment: (And why would milliseconds be 7100000? That seems very odd to me... not to mention almost certainly being useless, as you're not going to be measuring that accurately.)

Comment: the answer is simple "my Boss"

Comment: Jon Skeet is correct you want to use a timespan object.  You could also employ DateTime.Add, DateTime.Subtract methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ratePick(int h, int m, int s)
  {
     TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(h, m, s);
     double total = ts.TotalSeconds;
     linesPicked = Convert.ToDouble(total/lines);
```

Comment: This answer needs some explanation